# Connect to SQL Server named instance from Windows CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-ce, connection-string

I have a working connection string I stole from my desktop application,

```
Data Source=Timber\Test2;User ID=****;Password=****;
Initial Catalog=UTIL;Application Name=Handheld Shipping;Connect Timeout=1
```

which just connects to a named instance on SQL Server for testing. When I use the same connection string in my Windows CE application, I get a `SqlException`, Specified SQL server not found: Timber\Test2.

Is this a limitation of the SQL client in .NET Compact? Or does the connection string need to be in a different format for the Compact client?

The device I'm using is CE6.0 and my program is .NET Compact 3.5.

EDIT:
I'm connecting to a SQL Server 2008, on Server 2008. Connecting to the default instance works, just not the named instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's no limitation on the CE connection. In fact the only thing different between the CE connection and the desktop is that a CE device can do something that a desktop can't. Pass the user name and password using Integrated Security.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
  Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

see [Trusted Connection from a CE device](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

The problem is probably that the CE device can't see Timber\Test2 due to a network issue. Try Pinging Timber from your CE Device

Comment: Hmm, I can ping it from the device. And I just did a test, I can connect to the default instance from the device.

Comment: @Kratz. Didn't consider the Named Instance. Perhaps its the Named pipe. Try NET VIEW Timber to see if that resolves the name?

Comment: Interesting results on that, after typing NEW VIEW, it prompted me for my network password. If I run the test right after that, it connects to the named instance just fine. I guess this makes some sense if its connecting through a named pipe.

Comment: So i think the solution is to pass the username and password in the connection string since its not authenticated on the network. Wierd that you could connect to the default without being on the network but need it for a named instance.